# UITableView space between row and sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make a UITableView as close to the iOS settings view as possible:

[image]

How do i create the space between different sections? What's the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just select grouped style in the Interface Builder and it will separate the table per section, similar as is in the screenshot.

Here is an attachment:

[image]

Comment: This grouped options, is this for an amount of cells in a static TableView?

Comment: For your convenience I have deleted my answer since you already answered, because my page was open and then there were no answers when I opened the page.

Comment: i want something like grouped with sticky header  , how can i achieve it .

Answer (score 2):

Change Style of UITableView to "Grouped"

Answer (score 1):

try these..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 30; //according to your need..
}
```

i hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

First of all the iOS Settings doesn't use the ViewForSection otherwise the Section view would be placed in the top tableView.

You can return an empty containerView cell for that specific indexPath and stop didSelect in it, but remember to include the empty cells to the array you are using for other cells.

Comment: You can return ViewForSection nil or heightForHeaderView 1 in case you want to hide it. using cells for this kind of UI would be painful as you would need to check for every "section" that you want to separate

Comment: You are right but this could be one way if he is not using Sections but is getting data only from one array.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the footer height in the table as required:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```